# Can't install package control in Sublime text 2

Tags: ubuntu, package, sublimetext2

I'm using ubuntu 12.04. I did what it says on the website but I got this error:

```
import urllib2,os; pf='Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp=sublime.installed_packages_path(); os.makedirs(ipp) if not os.path.exists(ipp) else None; urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.ProxyHandler())); 
open(os.path.join(ipp,pf),'wb').write(urllib2.urlopen('http://sublime.wbond.net/'+pf.replace(' ','%20')).read()); print 'Please restart Sublime Text to finish installation'
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 13] Permiso denegado: u'/home/housepc/.config/sublime-text-2/Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package'

permiso denegado : "permission denied"
```

What could I do to install it?

Answer (score 24):

Just open terminal and execute this line:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 "/home/{youruser}/.config/sublime-text-2/Installed Packages/"
```

and try to install the package control again.

Comment: Wouldn't the chown answer be cleaner than the old 777 solution to all permissions problems?

Comment: Yes I think so, but many users still use chmod 777. The aim of both is block/allow permissions.

Comment: When installing subsequent packages, users may have to do the same for /Packages/ as well as /Installed Packages/ , which may be obvious to some but took me 30 minutes of frustration before I finally figured out.

Comment: @SoldierCorp as mattsheperd pointed out, some users will need to use "sudo chmod -R 777 "/home/{youruser}/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/".
Please add it to your answer

Comment: This is not a great solution. As commented, the `chown` approach is better, or setting the permissions to 755 instead of 777. Also, apply `chown` to the `sublime-text-2` folder is better since it kills problems related to write access in other folders within it. Basically, @Goddard answer is overall better.

Answer (score 19):

The easiest method is simply to run sublime text with sudo privalges.

I just pop open a terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

make sure you are the owner of the directory instead of root with

```
sudo chown -R {youruser}:{youruser}  "/home/{youruser}/.config/sublime-text-2"

sudo sublime
```

After that open the sublime text console with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and enter

```
import urllib2,os; pf='Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp=sublime.installed_packages_path(); os.makedirs(ipp) if not os.path.exists(ipp) else None; urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.ProxyHandler())); open(os.path.join(ipp,pf),'wb').write(urllib2.urlopen('http://sublime.wbond.net/'+pf.replace(' ','%20')).read()); print 'Please restart Sublime Text to finish installation'
```

After the initial install you can run sublime text normally.

Comment: Problem with this is that you will need to run sublime with sudo priviledges every time otherwise you wont have it with package control

Comment: check your package folder and make sure it has the correct permissions

Comment: @TechyTimo, I used this method successfully and it doesn't require sublime to run with sudo.

Comment: Nop, this works for me. It needs to run once more with the run priviledges, after that every thing go be all right. ^

Comment: As simple as this, `sudo subl` just runs sublime text as root, and then running the command is in the place of root. Thanks. Then you can `chown` and all the things, but first, let me install package control!

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe that `chmod -R 777`-ing is the best solution to this problem. Granted, it will let you install the package but I don't think that anyone should get into the habit of just opening the permissions floodgates anytime write-access is denied. In this case, it's really not a big deal. I don't think that your sublime-text packages folder is a high priority, but none-the-less getting into the habbit of allowing everyone write access could cause problems later down the line, especially if the end user is a new *nix user and doesn't know *why* they are changing permissions.

(Just as a note: I'm running sublime-text-3, but that shouldn't matter because this is a permission issue and not an issue with sublime-text itself)

In my case, I had two problems.

1. **Sublime-Text was installed to the correct directory, but was owned by root.**
   The first and obvious solution was to `sudo chown -R username:username /home/username/.config/sublime-text-3`. This returned control of the directory to me.
2. **The permissions on my installation somehow were set to something wonky.** (At some point something I must have done set them incorrectly. What that would have been or when slips my mind, but I have been known to do dumb things while sleep deprived during finals week)

   To fix this is also simple. `chmod -R 755 /home/username/.config/sublime-text-3/`. The allows for you to write to the directory, but not other people who shouldn't already be all ready be allowed to write there. Unless you intentionally want to give everyone write access  to a directory the most you should give is `775` which allows other users in the same group to write to that directory.

Like I said before, this isn't necessarily going to be a problem if any user on your system can write to your sublime-text packages folder. I don't see any real issues with it in itself, but getting into the habit of making something fully write-able could result in a mistake that opens your system up to vulnerabilities if you don't know the consequences of your actions.

Further reference: http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: I had the first problem

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would be to make the sublime-text folder writeable:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 "/home/{youruser}/.config/sublime-text-2/
```

or for sublime text 3:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 "/home/{youruser}/.config/sublime-text-3/
```

Then try to install package control again.

Answer (score 1):

Also, check that you're not on a proxy network.  I was only able to install Package Control after switching to a non-proxy network.

Answer (score 0):

After installing sublime text try :
`sudo /usr/bin/subl`

This worked for sublime text 3 on Ubuntu 12.04